# Running loop from javascript to save in Mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql

Hello i am currently running a javascript on my php page (below) and it comes out with each data that i need is there any way i can connect this through to mysql database? (i am new to javascript)

```
<script>
 var allItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemsArray')) || [];
for(var i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++) {
  var item = allItems[i];
  console.log('Current item: %o', item);

}
</script>
```

'itemsArray comes from a save function'

```
function save(){

var oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemsArray')) || [];

var newItem = {};
var num = document.getElementById("num").value;

newItem[num] = {
    "methv": document.getElementById("methv").value
    ,'q1': document.getElementById("q1").value,
    'q2':document.getElementById("q2").value,
    'q3':document.getElementById("q3").value,
    'q4':document.getElementById("q4").value,
    'comm':document.getElementById("comm").value
};


oldItems.push(newItem);

localStorage.setItem('itemsArray', JSON.stringify(oldItems));


});
```

Thanks

PS I already have the connection for the database setup

Comment: JavaScript executes on the client side. Usually, MySQL resides on the server. So to do that, you would have to do an AJAX request to the server to store/retrieve data. Unless this is a very weird scenario where MySQL would reside on the client machine, in which case I have no idea if it's possible with JavaScript, but I would guess that it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Post your data with ajax/json request to a php function and do all database related work with php. Next return successful or failure status which will be catch in this called js function, and then you can display the success or failure message with javascript.

Example:

Include jQuery library:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Script for ajax request with jQuery:

```
    var path = 'http:/your_url/your_php_script_file.php';
    var data = 'json_data=' + JSON.stringify(newItem[num]);
        $.ajax({
            url: path,
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function ($returm_msg){
                alert($returm_msg);
            }
        });
```

PHP for save/update in database:

```
$receive_value = json_decode($_POST['json_data'], true));
```

You will get values like

```
$receive_value['methv'],$receive_value['q1'],....,$receive_value['comm'];
```

Now do save operation in database.

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO .....") or die(mysql_error());
if($result){
    return "Success!"; // if not function then simply echo "Success!";
}else{
    return "Failure!"; // if not function then simply echo "Failure!";
}
```

Helpful links:

1. http://www.bennadel.com/resources/presentations/jquery/demo21/index.htm
2. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

Comment: Sorry i am kinda new with Ajax/Json could you show an example or a link please?

Comment: Learn about Ajax what it is and how it helps. Search for Ajax and you will find lots of sources to learn from. This community not for suggesting links to external sites

Comment: I would recommend against using the `mysql_*` function library, since it is deprecated.